# Using dplyr and lubridate to combine count and group by month and year

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, count, lubridate

I have a dataframe where each row represents a single occurrence that took place in a city. The dataframe displays the name of the city and the date of the occurrence, like so:

```
df <- data.frame(city = c("Seattle", "Seattle", "Seattle", "Seattle", "Seattle", "NYC", "NYC", "NYC", "Chicago",
                         "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago"),
                     date_of_event = c("01/13/2011", "01/17/2011", "03/15/2011", "05/21/2011", "05/23/2011",
                                      "01/20/2011", "01/22/2011", "03/23/2011", "01/18/2011", "02/24/2011",
                                       "02/26/2011", "04/30/2011", "06/18/2011"),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$date_of_event <- as.Date(df$date_of_event, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

The above is just an example, my data is actually in a csv with thousands of rows, many cities, many dates, etc. What I want to do is generate a new dataframe that has a row for each city and each month/year represented in the dataset, and a corresponding count column that displays how many occurrences took place in each city in each month in the original dataframe. That 2nd dataframe would look like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(city = c("Seattle", "Seattle", "Seattle", "Seattle", "Seattle", "Seattle", "NYC", "NYC", "NYC", "NYC",
                           "NYC", "NYC", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago"),
                     month_year = c("01/01/2011", "02/01/2011", "03/01/2011", "04/01/2011", "05/01/2011", "06/01/2011",
                                    "01/01/2011", "02/01/2011", "03/01/2011", "04/01/2011", "05/01/2011", "06/01/2011",
                                    "01/01/2011", "02/01/2011", "03/01/2011", "04/01/2011", "05/01/2011", "06/01/2011"),
                  count = c(2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2$month_year <- as.Date(df2$month_year, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

I know that you can use count from dplyr and also lubridate to round dates down to the first day of each month, but I've tried and failed to get the grouping and counting right in order to produce the 2nd dataframe I want.

Comment: Sorry, I should also mention that my initial dataframe does cover multiple years as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df3 <- df %>% mutate(new_date = floor_date(date_of_event, "month")) 
tt <- as.data.frame(table(df3[-2])) 
tt[order(desc(tt$city), tt$new_date),]

      city   new_date Freq
   Seattle 2011-01-01    2
   Seattle 2011-02-01    0
   Seattle 2011-03-01    1
   Seattle 2011-04-01    0
   Seattle 2011-05-01    2
   Seattle 2011-06-01    0
       NYC 2011-01-01    2
       NYC 2011-02-01    0
       NYC 2011-03-01    1
       NYC 2011-04-01    0
       NYC 2011-05-01    0
       NYC 2011-06-01    0
   Chicago 2011-01-01    1
   Chicago 2011-02-01    2
   Chicago 2011-03-01    0
   Chicago 2011-04-01    1
   Chicago 2011-05-01    0
   Chicago 2011-06-01    1
```

To include extended periods with zero count, you can try this:

```
# assign a name to the output obtained previously
df4 <- tt[order(desc(tt$city), tt$new_date),]

a <- mdy("01/01/11") # starting period 
b <- a + months(0:92)  # period sequence

df5 <- expand.grid(city = c("Chicago", "Seattle", "NYC"), new_date = as.factor(b)) 

df6 <- setdiff(df5, df4[-3])
df6$Freq <- 0 # assign zero count

df7 <- rbind(df4, df6)

df8 <- df7[order(df7$city, df7$new_date), ]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is so helpful. I do have one followup question: Do you know how I would tweak this code so that the new dataframe contains a row for every month in a specific time period, for every city? The above only has january through june 2011 (as that's what was in my sample dataframe), but what if I wanted there to be a row for every city, for every month between 01/01/2011 and 09/01/2018? i.e. if there was no entry for a given city for a certain month, it would just get a zero count?

Comment: @ben_p_4370 additional codes were added to the answer.